# How to make block collision in python opengl

Tags: python, opengl, glfw, pyopengl

I am trying to make block collision in Python PyOpenGL but I dont know how. I tried to do

```
for blocks in blockPositions:
    #make camera go back up again
```

in my loop but it makes my game slow. Im also new in PyOpenGL and was following some tutorials but learned nothing with collisions and stuff.
I googled alot about making collision in PyOpenGL but found nothing. I only found unrelated results like stuff with other languages and other modules.

my code:

```
import glfw
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import compileProgram, compileShader
import pyrr
from TextureLoader import load_texture
import numpy as np

from camera import Camera

cam = Camera()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1280, 720
lastX, lastY = WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2
first_mouse = True
left, right, forward, backward = False, False, False, False

def key_input_clb(window, key, scancode, action, mode):
    global left, right, forward, backward
    if key == glfw.KEY_ESCAPE and action == glfw.PRESS:
        glfw.set_window_should_close(window, True)

    if key == glfw.KEY_W and action == glfw.PRESS:
        forward = True
    elif key == glfw.KEY_W and action == glfw.RELEASE:
        forward = False
    if key == glfw.KEY_S and action == glfw.PRESS:
        backward = True
    elif key == glfw.KEY_S and action == glfw.RELEASE:
        backward = False
    if key == glfw.KEY_A and action == glfw.PRESS:
        left = True
    elif key == glfw.KEY_A and action == glfw.RELEASE:
        left = False
    if key == glfw.KEY_D and action == glfw.PRESS:
        right = True
    elif key == glfw.KEY_D and action == glfw.RELEASE:
        right = False

def do_movement():
    if left:
        cam.process_keyboard("LEFT", 0.05)
    if right:
        cam.process_keyboard("RIGHT", 0.05)
    if forward:
        cam.process_keyboard("FORWARD", 0.05)
    if backward:
        cam.process_keyboard("BACKWARD", 0.05)


def mouse_look_clb(window, xpos, ypos):
    global first_mouse, lastX, lastY

    if first_mouse:
        lastX = xpos
        lastY = ypos
        first_mouse = False

    xoffset = xpos - lastX
    yoffset = lastY - ypos

    lastX = xpos
    lastY = ypos

    cam.process_mouse_movement(xoffset, yoffset)


vertex_src = """
# version 330
layout(location = 0) in vec3 a_position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 a_texture;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 a_offset;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 move;
out vec2 v_texture;
void main()
{
    vec3 final_pos = a_position + a_offset;
    gl_Position =  projection * view * move * model * vec4(final_pos, 1.0f);
    v_texture = a_texture;
}
"""

fragment_src = """
# version 330
in vec2 v_texture;
out vec4 out_color;
uniform sampler2D s_texture;
void main()
{
    out_color = texture(s_texture, v_texture);
}
"""


def window_resize_clb(window, width, height):
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    projection = pyrr.matrix44.create_perspective_projection_matrix(45, width / height, 0.1, 100)
    glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, projection)


if not glfw.init():
    raise Exception("glfw can not be initialized!")

window = glfw.create_window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "My OpenGL window", None, None)

if not window:
    glfw.terminate()
    raise Exception("glfw window can not be created!")

glfw.set_window_pos(window, 400, 200)

glfw.set_window_size_callback(window, window_resize_clb)
glfw.set_cursor_pos_callback(window, mouse_look_clb)
glfw.set_key_callback(window, key_input_clb)
glfw.set_input_mode(window, glfw.CURSOR, glfw.CURSOR_DISABLED)

glfw.make_context_current(window)


cube_buffer = [-0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
             0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0, 0.0,
             0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0, 1.0,
            -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 0.0, 1.0,

            -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
             0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0, 0.0,
             0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0, 1.0,
            -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 1.0,

             0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
             0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0, 0.0,
             0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0, 1.0,
             0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 0.0, 1.0,

            -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
            -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0, 0.0,
            -0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0, 1.0,
            -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 0.0, 1.0,

            -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
             0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0, 0.0,
             0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0, 1.0,
            -0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 0.0, 1.0,

             0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
            -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0, 0.0,
            -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0, 1.0,
             0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 0.0, 1.0]

cube_buffer = np.array(cube_buffer, dtype=np.float32)

cube_indices = [ 0,  1,  2,  2,  3,  0,
                 4,  5,  6,  6,  7,  4,
                 8,  9, 10, 10, 11,  8,
                12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 12,
                16, 17, 18, 18, 19, 16,
                20, 21, 22, 22, 23, 20]

cube_indices = np.array(cube_indices, dtype=np.uint32)

shader = compileProgram(compileShader(vertex_src, GL_VERTEX_SHADER), compileShader(fragment_src, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))

VAO = glGenVertexArrays(1)
VBO = glGenBuffers(1)
EBO = glGenBuffers(1)

glBindVertexArray(VAO)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube_buffer.nbytes, cube_buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO)
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube_indices.nbytes, cube_indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, cube_buffer.itemsize * 5, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, cube_buffer.itemsize * 5, ctypes.c_void_p(12))

textures = glGenTextures(1)
load_texture("src/grass.png", textures)

instance_array = []
offset = 1

for z in range(0, 100, 2):
    for x in range(0, 100, 2):
        translation = pyrr.Vector3([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
        translation.x = x + offset
        translation.y = y + offset
        translation.z = z + offset
        instance_array.append(translation)

len_of_instance_array = len(instance_array) 
instance_array = np.array(instance_array, np.float32).flatten()

instanceVBO = glGenBuffers(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceVBO)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instance_array.nbytes, instance_array, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

glEnableVertexAttribArray(2)
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
glVertexAttribDivisor(2, 1) 

glUseProgram(shader)
glClearColor(0, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

projection = pyrr.matrix44.create_perspective_projection_matrix(45, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.1, 100)
cube_pos = pyrr.matrix44.create_from_translation(pyrr.Vector3([-50.0, -50.0, -200.0]))

model_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "model")
proj_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "projection")
view_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "view")
move_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "move")

glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, projection)
glUniformMatrix4fv(model_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, cube_pos)


while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
    glfw.poll_events()
    do_movement()

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    move = pyrr.matrix44.create_from_translation(pyrr.Vector3([0, 0, glfw.get_time()*8]))
    glUniformMatrix4fv(move_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, move)

    view = cam.get_view_matrix()
    glUniformMatrix4fv(view_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, view)

    glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, len(cube_indices), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None, len_of_instance_array)

    glfw.swap_buffers(window)


glfw.terminate()
```

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue. SO is not a provider for tutorials and I doubt anyone will read through 200+ lines of code to see what you do.

Comment: You might want to start f.e. here: [Collision-detection](https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/2D-Game/Collisions/Collision-detection) and adapt the code to python yourself.

Comment: OpenGL doesn't do collisions. at all.